# Shuffle Comma Separated Strings per Individual Row and Column (per field)

Tags: python, pandas, list, shuffle

I have a dataframe with rows of values that have been concatenated, but separated by a comma.

**Row1** foo,bar,test,case

**Row2** base,ball,basket,foot

The goal is the shuffle/randomize each fields values, will retaining row order (do not shuffle columns, index must be kept)
The hope is to return something like this:

**Row1** test,foo,case,bar

**Row2** ball,foot,base,basket

**SOLUTION FOUND:**

```
Original_DF = # Our csv loaded data - the DF contains multiple columns of data attached to primary

data_list=[e for e in Original_DF['Data_List']]   # each 'Data_List' field was one long string with a comma seperating words, we needed to make them a list

Shuff_DF=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(data_list)):
    myList=np.random.permutation(data_list[i].split(","))
    myString = ",".join(myList)
    Shuff_DF = Shuff_DF.append({'Data_List2': myString}, ignore_index=True)

Original_DF['Data_List2']=Shuff_DF['Data_List2'] # Append newly shuffled Lists to original df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.random.permutation to shuffle a list

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html

Example:

```
import numpy.random

mydata = "foo,bar,baz,bat"

print(numpy.random.permutation(mydata.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using pandas functionality (sample):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar", "test", "case"], 
                   "b": ["xoo", "xar", "xest", "xase"]})
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].sample(frac=1).values
```

Probably there is a more elegant approach avoiding the for loop, using apply.

PS: Alternatively, modifying the other answer from @Simon Crane:

```
df.apply(np.random.permutation, axis=0)
```